# Как добавить записи из одной таблицы в другую из разных БД?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Есть два одинаковых сайта, один из них тестовый, для экспериментов. Клиент случайно добавил новые товары в базу на тестовый сайт. 
Хочу вытащить эти записи из БД, никогда этого не делала, почитала курс по SQL, план такой:
 1. Вытащить эти записи запросом из таблицы с продуктами и создать из них новую таблицу:

```
SELECT * INTO 'test_products' FROM `nkvzs_jshopping_products` WHERE `date_modify`> '2017-09-17 00:00:00.000';
```

2. Экспортировать новую таблицу из базы и импортировать её в базу основного сайта.
3. Слить две таблицы вместе командой

   SELECT * FROM `frdsy_jshopping_products` 
        UNION 
        SELECT * FROM `test_products`;

Но новая таблица не создаётся автоматически, phpmyadmin ругается, что она не существует. Вручную создавать не хочется. 
Это вообще правильный ход мыслей? Как правильно действовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если **формат баз данных у обоих сайтов одинаковый**, и при этом товары **не имеют внешних связей по каким-либо полям**, то возможно можно поступить проще:

1. **Важно**. Сделать бекапы обоих сайтов и их баз
2. Выделить товары для переноса в том же PHPMyAdmin (вручную или выбрать через SELECT и выделить все выбранные)
3. Нажать "Экспорт" на панельке внизу таблицы. Выбранные записи преобразуются в текст SQL запроса, в итоге после шаманств с настройками можно получить просто набор INSERT для этой же базы данных
4. Взять получившийся текст SQL и выполнить его на боевой базе данных
5. При ругани на PRIMARY KEY из запросов INSERT удалить значения PRIMARY KEY из обоих частей INSERT - ну то есть предоставить БД самой ставить значение PRIMARY KEY
6. В случае ошибки или отличия результата от желаемого вернуться к пункту 1, восстановив данные из сделанных бекапов. Обдумать ошибки и повторить

Если же к товарам привязаны файлы, изображения, какие-то связи и так далее - то просто смешать или добавить в чистом SQL не получится. Нужно персонально подходить к задаче, выяснять логику каждого поля и грамотно их перенести. Лучше скриптом, подключенным сразу к двум БД. Берем из первой, анализируем, аккуратно вставляем во вторую

UPD: В случае, если у записей есть связи, нужно вынимать запись целиком, вместе со всеми связями

Это значит, что если к примеру у записи А есть еще три связанных записи AB, AC, AD в других таблицах (изображения, документы, права, статистика просмотров, что-то еще), то проще сделать скрипт с примерно следующим алгоритмом:

1. Подключиться к тестовой БД
2. Вынуть интересующие нас записи
3. Вынуть все связанные с ними записи
4. Отключиться от тестовой БД, подключиться к боевой БД
5. Добавить все связанные материалы в соответствующие таблицы (AB, AC, AD из примера выше). Получить новое значение поля, по которому строится связь
6. В основной записи A поменять все поля, отвечающие за связи, на новые значения из связанных AB, AC, AD
7. Добавить основную запись с обновленными значениями связей

Это сложные операции, на чистом SQL делать их довольно трудно. Проще написать скрипт, которому дается идентификатор записи в тестовой БД, которую нужно перенести в боевую. И переносить их скриптом, аккуратно

Comment: Да, там, конечно, несколько таблиц связано, таблица изображений точно есть. Но ведь с ними со всеми можно эту последовательность операций выполнить.
Разве в phpmyadmin можно экспортировать выбранные записи? У меня получалось либо таблицу целиком, либо "начиная с какой-то".
И вот это я не поняла: "в итоге после шаманств с настройками можно получить просто набор INSERT для этой же базы данных".
Разве там не просто таблица получается, а её только импортировать в новую базу можно?

Comment: Если у вас формат одинаковый, вам таблица без надобности сама. Нужны записи этих таблиц, чтобы их вставить в боевую БД. А проблема с изображениями и тд в том, что связи в тестовой БД будут гарантировано не совпадать с боевой БД. Например у вас есть запись с image_id=53, а в боевой БД вообще такого изображения нет, или (что еще хуже) image_id=53 уже занято другим изображением.

Comment: В phpMyAdmin я просто смотрю в Обзоре на таблицу, ставлю например 4 галочки слева от нужных мне записей, тыкаю ссылку под таблицей Обзора "Экспорт" и в настройках экспорта говорю "Отобразить как текст", в итоге получаю текст SQL для вставки этих 4 строк в виде `INSERT (<fields>) VALUES (<r1>), (<r2>), (<r3>), (<r4>)`. Если убрать поле PRIMARY KEY из всех строк и списка полей `<fields>`, то этот запрос можно выполнить на боевой базе, и добавить 4 интересующие нас строки в боевую базу

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил рекомендации по поводу переноса записей со связями. Совет общий, требует от вас осмысления. Удачи! )

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли, кажется, получилось!

Comment: Очень рад за вас, если вам помог ответ - отметьте его как верный, пожалуйста. Это поможет другим участникам сообщества сориентироваться ) и мне будет приятно

Answer (score 0):

> новая таблица не создаётся автоматически

И не должна. Создайте её явно запросом

```
CREATE TABLE test_products LIKE nkvzs_jshopping_products;
```

А потом уже вставляйте в неё нужные записи.

> Слить две таблицы вместе командой

Запрос SELECT ничего не "сливает". Ну то есть одним списком Вы записи, конечно, увидите, но от этого они в одну таблицу не сольются, вывод записей совсем даже не хранение.

> Это вообще правильный ход мыслей?

Скажем так - один из многочисленных сравнительно правильных, ну или похожих на правильный. Не зная схемы БД, сказать, совсем он правильный, частично, или к правильному и близко не лежал, увы, невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо, полезно.
Результат работы команды UNION просто список? А как этот результат сохранить в таблицу? Через UPDATE или INSERT можно?

Comment: Ну либо `INSERT INTO ... (SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...)`, либо `UPDATE ... , (SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...) AS ... SET ...`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я поняла. А как избежать ошибки дублирования по первичному ключу? UPDATE заменит записи, а INSERT ругается на дубли по id_product.

Comment: *как избежать ошибки дублирования по первичному ключу?* Раз [phpmyadmin], то, вероятно, [mysql]. Тогда INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE либо REPLACE. А дубли в таблицах-источниках сами отсеются, ибо UNION DISTINCT.

Comment: Большое спасибо!